# Как записать данные из разных ячеек в одну DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Пытался написать ресурс, который бы выводил полное имя клиента в одно поле datagrid, но не получается пишет "не удаётся преобразовать из "string" в "dbcontext.Client."
Разметка

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Клиент" Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource list},
                                XPath=Client, Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

код ресурса

```
namespace StraxCompany.Model
{
    class ClientList : ObservableCollection<Clinet>
    {
        public ClientList()
        {
            var names = Documents.dbcontext.Clinet
                   .Select(c => new
                   {
                       fname = c.First_Name,
                       lname = c.Last_Name,
                       mname = c.Middle_Name
                   });
            foreach (Clinet name in names)
            {
                //qwe.Add(name.lname+" "+name.fname+" "+name.mname);
                this.Add(name.lname + name.fname  + name.mname);
                //this.Add(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс клиент

```
namespace StraxCompany
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Clinet
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Clinet()
        {
            this.Treatly = new HashSet<Treatly>();
        }
    
        public int ID_Client { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Middle_Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Treatly> Treatly { get; set; }
    }}
```

Comment: Вставьте код текстом, пожалуйста. Начало и в конец кода можно ограничить символами ``` на отдельной строке.

Comment: У вас опечатка в названии класса `Client` наверное. Попробуйте `foreach (Client name in names)`, и я не рекомендую использовать ключевое слово `var` до тех пор, пока вы окончательно не разберетесь, как оно работает.

Comment: Покажите код класса `Client` и разметку `DataGrid`. У вас автогенерация колонок?

Comment: @aepot Автогенерация отключена, foreach(Client name in names) не сработало, пишет "Не удается преобразовать тип "<anonymous type: string fname, string lname, string mname>" в "StraxCompany.Clinet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте свойство, которое будет Собирать ФИО в одну строку

```csharp
public partial class Clinet
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Clinet()
    {
        this.Treatly = new HashSet<Treatly>();
    }
    
    public int ID_Client { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Middle_Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Full_Name => Last_Name + " " + First_Name + " " + Middle_Name;

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Treatly> Treatly { get; set; }
}
```

А в цикле вот так

```csharp
foreach (var name in names)
{
    Clinet client = new Clinet()
    {
        First_Name = name.fname,
        Last_Name = name.lname,
        Middle_Name = name.mname
    }
    this.Add(client);
}
```

Ну и колонка

```xaml
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Клиент" Binding="{Binding Full_Name}"/>
```

И советую все-таки переименовать класс `Clinet` в `Client`